# Starting a thread with class name

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class MyRunnableTask implements Runnable {
   public void run() {
     // do stuff here
   }
 }
```

Is it possible to start a thread of the above class with just the class name?

Update:

I tried as @zhh commented and it worked. We need to create an object of the class using reflection

Sample code:

```
    public class Runner2 implements Runnable {

        volatile int count =0;

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Inside runner 2 -"+LocalTime.now());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void shutdown() {
            System.out.println("shuutting down");
        }

    }



    public class Test_thread {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {

            Class<?> myclass = Class.forName("Runner2");
            Constructor<?> constructor = myclass.getConstructor();
            System.out.println(myclass);

            Object obj=constructor.newInstance(new Object[] {});
            Runnable run = (Runnable)obj;

            Thread t = new Thread(run);
            t.start();

            Method m = myclass.getMethod("shutdown");

            m.invoke(obj);

        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to create an object with only class name you can use java reflection.

Comment: yeah, but is there a way to start a thread with that object?

Comment: ```new Thread(MyRunnableTaskObject).start()```. You can use reflection to create an instance of ```MyRunnableTask```, but why do you want to do this? There might be other better ways instead of reflection.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help pages [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if it's possible.